# NSInternalInconsistencyException in insertRowsAtIndexPaths

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm trying to implement `insertRowsAtIndexPaths` for my table view.

Before this implementation, I used to call `[self.tableView reloadData]` after user hit end of table. This method kinda impacted my app quality for lots of row and lots of scrolling.(freezing each time before reloading data)

So I used this code instead:

```
p.lastid = appRecord.ids;
[p main];
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void)
        {                                    
         [self.tableView beginUpdates];
         NSArray *temp = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[p.appRecordList count] inSection:0]];
         [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:temp withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
         [self.tableView endUpdates];

          });
      });
    }
    return cell;
}
```

The old working code was:

```
  NSArray *temp =[self.entries arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:p.appRecordList];
  self.entries = temp;
  [self.tableView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
```

`p.appRecordList` is an `NSArray` and the new row item is from hayoola fetch.

For `numberOfRowInSection` I use this:

```
#define kCustomRowCount     10
@property (nonatomic, assign) int intindex;
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSUInteger count = [self.entries count];
    if (count == 0)
    {
        return kCustomRowCount;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Also there is no `cellforRowAtIndexPath` in my code.
I should mention that my program will fetch 10 row each time from serve r.

This is the Console error code:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to insert row 10 into section 0, but there are only 10 rows in section 0 after the update'*

edit :(change due to answer)

after changing the update method to this :

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
NSArray *temp_1 =[self.entries arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:p.appRecordList];
self.entries = temp_1;
NSArray *temp = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[p.appRecordList count] inSection:0]];
[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:temp withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

and `insertRowsAtIndexPaths` to this :

```
    NSUInteger count = [self.entries count];
    return count;
```

this error appears :

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (20) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (10), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (1 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ensure that the additional record(s) have been added to `self.entries` before the call to `endUpdates`. The exception is telling you that you tried to add an 11th row, but `numberOfRowsInSection` returned 10

You need ensure that you insert the same number of rows as elements added to your array

Your update method should be

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];

NSMutableArray *newIndices=[NSMutableArray new];

for (id record in p.appRecordList) {
   [self.entries addObject:record];
   [newIndicies addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:self.entries.count]];
}


[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:newIndices withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

Comment: Thanks for answer , can u help me , in what way i can achieve this ?
how and where should i update "numberOfRowsInSection " ?

Comment: Your `numberOfRowsInSecfion` returns the number of entries in your array, so if you update the array it should be right - except of the array is empty, you return 10 - why do you do this?  This means that the first time you add something to the array you must insert the new row but delete the 10 "fake" rows

Comment: so if i just remove "    if (count == 0)
    {
        return kCustomRowCount;
    }"  , there is no need to modify anything else then ?

Comment: As long as you are adding the item to your array, no.

Comment: Thanks For info , another error just happend. im updating my question for new error

Comment: You are only calling insertRows once, but it seems that you have added 10 objects to your array - the number of inserts must be consistent with the new number of objects in the array

Comment: Now im kinda confused. "temp_1" is going to have new array item and then after this line "self.entries = temp_1" the datasource will be 20 item.in "temp" im stroing new new items that comes from "p.apprecordlist" (10 item). so new datasource is 20 and item to insert is 10. am i missing something ?